# Cannot set property of undefined -- inserting text with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

[image]I am currently trying to insert some text in a specific spot at a website, http://kawowii.com , however, I keep getting error messages. These error messages seem to originate from the section I am trying to select using javascript (variables txtClasses and styleClasses). The error messages are

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of undefined

So, the variables seem to be undefined but I don't understand why. I have looked at the other answers and still cannot determine what is wrong.

Right now, I have

```
window.onload = function() {
    var txtClasses = document.querySelectorAll("div.coord-control.leaflet-control");
    txtClasses[0].textContent = "Server: UP Location:"
}
```

and I tried this

```
window.onload = function() {
    var styleClasses = document.querySelectorAll(".coord-control leaflet-control");
    function insertAfter1(referenceNode, newNode) {
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
    }
    var brk = document.createElement("br");
    insertAfter1(styleClasses[0], brk);
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var textNode = document.createTextNode("Server: UP")
    div.appendChild(textNode);
    insertAfter1(brk, div);
}
```

My end goal is to change the website, kawowii.com , such that before `Location :`, it reads `Server: UP` using javascript.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is tagged with jquery when you're using the raw DOM. Anyways, check your selectors. txtClasses is apparently returning 0 results, so referencing 0 in an array (really, a NodeList) will give undefined, and you can't reference a property of undefined.

Comment: I can use jQuery so I tagged it.

Comment: You'll get that error if there are no elements matching the selector, since `txtClasses[0]` is undefined.

Comment: The elements match, I have doubled and triple checked they exist as the same as I have written.

Comment: Your second code block is missing the `.` before `leaflete-control`. Is leaflet-control the same element of `coord-control` or is inside it? Can you post a sample of the HTML?

Comment: are you sure? It's looking for a div that has both the coord-control and leaflet-control classes. Is that what it should be looking for?

Comment: Yeah. It is all dynamically generated by javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed `document.querySelectorAll("div.coord-control.leaflet-control");` on the website you provided, and it *does* in fact show an array with that element.

I think `div.coord-control.leaflet-control` is being inserted dynamically (perhaps after an AJAX request completes).

Therefore, you need to put your controlling logic inside the callback of the request:

```
whateverRequestIsInsertingThatElement.then(function() {
    var txtClasses = document.querySelectorAll("div.coord-control.leaflet-control");
    txtClasses[0].textContent = "Server: UP Location:"
});
```

I don't know if you're using promises or if the async method you're using provides a callback, but `onload` will happen in parallel with your async request, so you need to query for the dynamic element in the callback of the async request.

---

Not sure which API you're using to generate the map on your website, but usually any calls for location data will happen asynchronously (like the Google Maps API, for example). You can only manipulate dynamically generated DOM elements once the data has arrived.

## Edit

You can see that the client is initially getting the configuration data from the route `up/configuration`. I would suggest looking for where that async call is being made in your source code, and then call `querySelectorAll` in its success handler.

I also see that in some of your sources, `$.ajax` is being called, so I assume somewhere in there, `$.ajax` is being called to the `up/configuration` route on your server.

[image: output]

Comment: Yeah, I think this is what's happening. The code is being run on window load, which is very likely to happen before the dynamic content is generated.

Comment: Is there a way to insert it without finding the controlling logic?

Comment: @ActionON unfortunately probably not. The DOM manipulation needs to happen in the success callback of your asynchronous request.

Comment: @ActionON, what API are you calling to get your map data on that site?

Comment: No idea, don't think it is really an API. The backend is written with java and the entire thing is a minecraft plugin called dynmap.

Comment: @ActionON You're going to have to find some way to determine that the element generation is complete. I don't know enough about the system to say what that is. You're just going to have to muck around in the code to find some way to tell.

Comment: @ActionON, using API as a generic term, if you're making an async request to your server, then your server is the "API". It looks like an async request is pinging `up/configuration`.

Comment: then yeah, the server is the API, hosting the minecraft map which shows the changes in real time on the web map.

Comment: @ActionON, I've edited the answer. If I were you I'd open up your dev tools and look in the network tab for XHRs. This will give you an idea of where/how the async request is being made.

Comment: There is a file called coord.js , I believe that is where I'm supposed to insert the javascript. My problem is when I added some text, nothing showed up on the server and there were no errors I could see either. It may be my javascript isn't good enough too. Have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

So what I imagine happening is this:

You are querying your page for a your leaflet control but its returning an array of nothing. So when you try and access txtClasses[0] its undefined (since txtClasses.length == 0).

```js
// this illustrates your problem
try {
  
  // I am manually creating an empty array (your results)
  var txtClasses = []
  
  // this throws the error
  txtClasses[0].bad = "throws an error";
  
} catch (e) {
  
  // this just displays the error for you to see
  document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += e.toString()
}
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

If you are expecting something back, you should check your selector is actually working (what I like to do is open up a web console and type my code right in there).

I noticed your selector changed in the first and second example too so make sure you read more about css selectors [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).